# Framer motion initial animation on first page load is broken but refreshing gives desired outcome

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, animation, framer-motion

I am currently having an issue using framer motion where when I initially load into my site the dynamic components of animation becoming broken. I currently have a 3 div row of elements using flex-col so they are stacked on top of one another and basically when they are animating in from off screen their timing is off and their y-values are about 10px's above where they should be before correcting themselves halfway through the animation.

One of my animations:

```
const topAnimation = useAnimation();
const topAnimation1 = useAnimation();


  useEffect(() => {
    const animateSequence = async () => {
      const yValues = [30, 0, 0];
      const scaleVal = [1.4, 1.0, 1.0];
      
      for (let i = 0; i < yValues.length; i++) {
        await topAnimation.start({
          y: yValues[i],
          scale: scaleVal[i],
          transition: {
            type: "spring",
            stiffness: 100,
            damping: 13,
            delay: i === 0 ? 2.1 : 1.5,
          },
        });
      }
    };

    animateSequence();
  }, [topAnimation]);


  useEffect(() => {
    const animateSequence = async () => {
      const yValues = [30, 0, 0];
      const scaleVal = [1.4, 1.0, 1.0];
      const xOffset = [45, 11, 0];

      for (let i = 0; i < yValues.length; i++) {
        await topAnimation1.start({
          y: yValues[i],
          scale: scaleVal[i],
          x: xOffset[i],
          transition: {
            type: "spring",
            stiffness: 100,
            damping: 13,
            delay: i === 0 ? 2.15 : 1.5,
          },
        });
      }
    };

    animateSequence();
  }, [topAnimation1]);
```

One of my components:

```
        <div className="flex gap-x-4 items-center">
          <motion.div
            initial={{ y: 140 }}
            animate={topAnimation}
            style={{ transformOrigin: "center center" }}
          >
            <Image
              src="/control-ani.svg"
              alt="controller"
              width={75}
              height={50}
              className=""
            />
          </motion.div>
          <motion.h1
            initial={{ y: 140 }}
            animate={topAnimation1}
            style={{ transformOrigin: "center center" }}
          >
            different use cases
          </motion.h1>
        </div>
```

I have tried to adjust the initial values to be set using ````topAnimation.set({})``` and that didn't help I also thought that maybe using two different functions for the animation with the awaits could be the issue but changing that changed basically nothing also.